# Add new aspx page to the SharePoint Site created on the basis of BlankSite template

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I would like to add more pages to my SherPoint Site created with blanksite template.

Now I have **my-machine.sp/mysite/mysubsite/default.aspx**
(mysubsite is created with STS#1 template)

Now I need to add more pages to this site programmatically: for example:

**my-machine.sp/mysite/mysubsite/page1.aspx**
**my-machine.sp/mysite/mysubsite/page2.aspx**

Pages can be the same like default.aspx because I need to add WebParts to them in the future.

I will be grateful for any information, links or code sample. In the network I found only examples with PublishingSites and some unclear examples, using SherePoint designer.

Other question is: Is it better to use other templates to achieve my goal (create subsite, add many pages, add webparts to them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the easiest way how to copy existing page to new location is open the SPWeb object get the page as SPFile and copy the SPFile to new location

```
SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPFile fileToCopy = currentWeb.GetFile("default.aspx");
fileToCopy.CopyTo("yourNew.aspx");
```

if you source file is ghosted, this new aspx will be ghosted as well.

Comment: Thx. It is what I now need. I wasted hours trying with PublishingWeb, SitePages Libaraies etc.